# Is dog food made specifically for Yorkie better than dog food made for all dogs?

Tags: health, feeding

I am about to get a new Yorkie puppy from a breeder. She currently feeds her dogs Blue Diamond dog food. From what I have read online, been told by breeders, and pet shops, that isn't recommended food. It's not very good.

Most of the dogs I have had were a Siberian Huskies and I have always given them "Taste of the Wild". There are some kinds of dog food that are advertised as being made specifically for Yorkies.

Would it be better if I fed my yorkie dog food that was made specifically for Yorkies? Or would it be fine if I fed it the same food as I have the huskies?

Comment: What are your arguments to say that "diamond"/"blue" are not good? Do they apply to the Yorkie specific food you're envisaging?

Comment: No arguments. It's just what I was told by two vets, and two pet stores, and online.  Overall the typical arguments are that it's not healthy, and the large recall awhile back might factor into the feedback I've been receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have to distinguish between people who are knowledgeable and people who are truly experts.  Pet store employees have varying degrees of knowledge, as do breeders, but I would never believe they are experts at dog nutrition.  I would trust a trained veterinarian, or a real dog nutritionist (with scientific training) over the advice of knowledgeable people.  Simply put, this question is not truly answerable without a scientific study and empirical data.

When it comes to food marketed to specific breeds or ages, again I take that information with a grain of salt.  I do believe there are some kernels of truth in the marketing.  Take food marketed for puppies.  They often advertise it has more of the vitamins needed for puppy development.  I have no reason to doubt that more of those vitamins are present, however I question whether the increase actually has quantifiable effect.  Remember, there are plenty of puppies who do not eat puppy formulated food and turn out just fine.

The same thing applies to foods marketed to different breeds of dogs.

I want to reiterate, there are some truths behind the marketing.  While a yorkie will most probably be fine eating food for a great dane, the size of the food is tailored towards bigger dogs and a smaller dog can choke.

In the end, the only person who can guide you in the right direction is your vet.

Comment: You have the best answer, but I want to share a little story her as a side note to other people reading this question. I gave my dog the same dog food for awhile, it was the grain free diet stuff. One day I didn't have enough money for her specific type of food and used a cheaper brand. She almost died. I spent 1,100 dollars keeping her alive when that happened. I guess being that smile she couldn't handle a rapid diet change. She's fine now but it took several trips to the emergency vet and vet, and they had to keep her over night.

Comment: Just one point: Puppy food has a much higher level of proteins, that's not just marketing. For age groups, yes checking the ingredients and the ratio is important. For sick dogs, pregnant or skinny dogs, it's not bad to switch to the puppy formula to help them get back in shape. Opinion: Pet stores (especially) and vets are not all experts with dog food, sometimes are in conflict of interest and have their specialty (or none) as well. Personally, I'd ask high quality kennel owners, they usually don't work alone and are surrounded by different specialists (eg. the best vets who are specialists)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what kind of breed you have, dogs are dogs! If the yorkie is fine with the huskies' food, then go for it!

But one thing the Yorkie has issue with that is specific to this breed is tartar issue. So in general, it's good to feed your yorkie mostly with dry food and give him toys that will help it clean its teeth. That doesn't stop you from serving it some canned food sometimes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yorkshire_Terrier#Teeth

One thing I noticed about the Blue Diamond food that it contains BHA and when possible, you should try to find another product that doesn't contain this artificial preservative. Same goes for BHT and TBHQ. You can look for food that uses vitamin E/tocopherols instead.

Often, when pet shops suggest dog food for small breed, the main benefit for the dog is the size of the bites! So that's one thing you can look for, and also a high protein food that doesn't contain too much corn, preferably rice as it's easier for dogs to digest.

You probably already know how to read the food labels, and the first ingredient is the one that has the biggest quantity in the mix. Ideally, you should avoid the dog food that starts with anything corn or grains, and go for meat instead. You will find labels that say "chicken" and others with "chicken flours" for example; I personally suggest you to go for the chicken first and then the flour as second best choice. At this point when you see these 2 as first ingredients, you're already serving your dog a very good quality food compared to the "grain flour" food.

http://pets.webmd.com/dogs/guide/how-to-read-a-dog-food-label